# Get client resource ID of client that disconnects in ratchet php in realtime

Tags: php, websocket, client, ratchet

Code im using:

```
protected $clients;

public function __construct() {
    $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
}

public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    $this->clients->attach($conn);

}

public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    $this->clients->detach($conn);

}
```

When a client disconnects the Onclose function is triggered, is there a way I can put the client resource Id in a variable and interact with it. If not, how would I tell which client disconnected in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    $a = array();
    $b = array();

    //Gets all the client Ids
    foreach($this->clients as $client){
        array_push($a,$client->resourceId);
    }

    //Deletes the disconnected client
    $this->clients->detach($conn);

    //Gets all the new client Ids
    foreach($this->clients as $client){
        array_push($b,$client->resourceId);
    }

    //array is made that includes the disconnceted client id by comparing both arrays made earlier
    $closedClientArray = array_diff($a,$b);

    //Client id is extracted from array and put in variable as a string
    $closeClientString = $closedClientArray[array_keys($closedClientArray)[0]];

    }
```